# How to set padding for Text inside ToggleButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-togglebutton

`ToggleButton` has default padding around text if `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` is set. I wanted to remove all padding around text and I found out that it is achieved by setting `android:minWidth="0dp"`. Now I could set padding to 10dp, but it will cut text at the end. Is there any way how to fix that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ToggleButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:background="@color/colorTextBlue"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="TextB"
    android:textOff="@null"
    android:textOn="@null"
    android:button="@null"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/toggle_color_selector" />
```

I will use custom drawable background for this button but here is some look of that button in preview:

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce that. Above code works properly. Is it only in preview or in app also?

Comment: It is in app too